# write different size vector into file row by row

Tags: r

I am the beginner of R language. I want to write different size vector into csv. Here is code:

```
library(igraph)
library(DirectedClustering)
my_list = readLines("F://RR//listtest.csv")
eigen <-c()
for(i in 1:length(my_list))
{

  my_data <- read.csv(my_list[i],head=TRUE, row.names =1 )
  my_matrix <-as.matrix(my_data)
  g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(my_matrix, weighted=TRUE,diag = FALSE)
  e1 <- eigen_centrality(g1,directed = TRUE)
  eigen[[i]] <-e1[["vector"]]  
}
df = data.frame(eigenvalue,eigen)
df
write.csv(df, "F://RR//outtest.csv")
```

The first question is due to different size of vector (the max is 14), the data.frame can not be used.
The second question is when i use the same size of vector to write into some csv file,it will display
like

```
 - Vec1 Vec2 Vec3
1. 2.5  3.5  4.5
2. 1.8  1.6  1.4
3. 1.3  5.8  9.9
```

but i wanna it display row by row, something like:

- 1 2.5
- 2 3.5
- 3 4.5
- 4 1.8
- 5 1.6
- 6 1.4
- 7 1.3
- 8 5.8
- 9 9.9

I really need your help, thanks lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read about [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your second question is easy enough to answer, but I don't quite understand what you are getting at with your first question. What is the size unit, and why can it only be 14?

Comment: the size of vector can be 11,12,13,14,so there are different size of vector.